# Is there a way to suppress notifications for "Tapbacks"?

Tags: messages, notifications

Is there a way to suppress notifications for Messages "Tapbacks", without surpassing other Messages notifications?

I'd like to continue receiving notifications for messages as I currently have them configured, but want to disable notifications for (only) "Tapbacks" because – (I can't possibly need to explain why). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You really don't need to explain why. Tapback is the most stupid useless and stressing feature Apple ever implemented.